# assume role policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Conditions must be prefaced by a vendor

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is my complete code trying to create an iam role and attach assume_role_policy which needs to look like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*removed*:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::*removed*:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:*removed*/*:*",
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My code is:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "eit_terraform_role" {
  name                = "${local.default_resource_name}-teraform"
  path                = "/"
  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"]
  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eit_terraform_role_assume_role_pipeline_policy.json
  inline_policy {
    name   = "inline"
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eit_terraform_role_assume_role_local_policy.json
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eit_terraform_role_assume_role_pipeline_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::*removed*:root"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]

    principals {
      type        = "Federated"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
      variable = "sts.amazonaws.com"
      values   = ["token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
      variable = "repo:*removed*/*:*"
      values   = ["token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eit_terraform_role_assume_role_local_policy" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["arn:aws:iam::*:role/eit-platform-engineer"]
  }
}
```

When I run terraform plan its fine, but when i apply code i get the following error:

> Error: updating IAM Role (eit-management-backend-teraform) assume role policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Conditions must be prefaced by a vendor.

The problem is with the conditions as it applies the changes fine without them. The conditions are in the data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eit_terraform_role_assume_role_pipeline_policy" resource.

The documentation shows the syntax as correct as shown here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#example-multiple-condition-keys-and-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have swapped the `values` and `variable` values:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eit_terraform_role_assume_role_pipeline_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::*removed*:root"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]

    principals {
      type        = "Federated"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
      variable = "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud"
      values   = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
      variable = "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub"
      values   = ["repo:*removed*/*:*"]
    }
  }
}
```

If you are looking at the JSON policy, you have the thing that you want to test first (`"ForAllValues:StringLike"`), followed by the variable you want to test (e.g., `"token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub"`) for a certain set of values (e.g., `["repo:*removed*/*:*"]`). In other words, what you want to check is: if for any string value the variable "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub" is equal to "repo:*removed*/*:*". You might also want to take a look at the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#understanding-the-oidc-token).

Comment: Awesome @Marko E that was the issue, many thanks for your time and education on this.